# how can i add a please wait call to this kind of links

Tags: javascript

I have the links like this

```
<a class="righto" href="http://localhost:8888/projectApp/index.cfm?frame=actions&id=100" target="detail" onclick="object(1);">Click Me</a>
```

i am also using `jquery`, but where i am using `jquery`, i am able to do a please wait, but how can do it here

any clue, because there is no `jquery` involved, its just a direct load link

i tried adding the code into js onclick but no luck

Comment: What do you mean a call waiting? Do you want the person to click on the link to wait a while to be directed to the url?

Comment: means showing a please wait instead of a white screen

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to do this in this case because you are working with a direct link, where the user chooses to go or not, so in theory he should already be directed immediately. Unless when the customer accesses the link before something must be loaded on that page